# Excel: search cell and get sum

Tags: excel, loops, sum, cell

In Excel, I'd like to iterate through the contents of a text cell, pulling the number found in in  each parenthesis, and add these numbers up in an adjacent cell.

For example, if A1 included:

> Conference call (.9); draft timetable (.5); update fact and witness
>   tables (1.2); scheduling team calls (.5); review edits, incorporate
>   changes (2.3); review draft skeleton (.5); team call (1.6)

I'd like B1 to include: 7.5

I would only be using parenthesis to store these numbers, so there's no risk of accidentally pulling text.

I'd be grateful for your tips!

NB: I'm very new to Excel (and this is my first post to Stack Overflow).  My apologies for the absence of a first crack at this code.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant method of gathering the bracketed numbers through RegEx but this *User Defined Function* (aka *UDF*) gathers the sum through text parsing fairly well.

```
Public Function udf_Sum_Nums(sBLURB As String)
    Dim sTMP As String, dTMP As Double
    sTMP = Replace(sBLURB, Chr(41), Space(9))
    Do While CBool(InStr(1, sTMP, Chr(40)))
        dTMP = dTMP + CDbl(Trim(Mid(sTMP, InStr(1, sTMP, Chr(40)) + 1, 9)))
        sTMP = Trim(Mid(sTMP, InStr(1, sTMP, Chr(40)) + 9, 9999))
    Loop
    udf_Sum_Nums = dTMP
End Function
```

Put this code into a *Module* code sheet in the VBE and it will be available as a native worksheet function.

[image: UDF Sum Bracketed Numbers]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *User Defined Function*

```
Public Function Addparen(s As String) As Double
    ss = Replace(s, ")", "(")
    ary = Split(ss, "(")
    xsum = 0
    For Each a In ary
        If IsNumeric(a) Then
            xsum = xsum + CDbl(a)
        End If
    Next a
    Addparen = xsum
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**